# What are constrained templates?

Tags: c++, c++14

Herb Sutters mentioned constrained templates (a.k.a. Concepts Lite) in the talk: [Modern C++: What You Need to Know](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661).

I know that boost has a concepts package in for ages, that allows one to pretty print error messages, when template deduction mechanism fails to find operators, functions or has access violation patterns.

I've encountered mentions on the [isocpp blog](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s) that there is already an experimental branch of [gcc](http://concepts.axiomatics.org/~ans/) implementing the [document proposing Concepts Lite](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3351.pdf). However looking through the current [C++14 draft](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf) I couldn't find any hints whether this will be already part of `C++14`.

So the questions are simple:

- will Concepts Lite be part of C++14? (Reference in the standard preferred. I could not find one, and I'm not very familiar with the standard.)
- what is the correct syntax of it? (The proposal and the slides of Herb diverge here and I don't know which one is more up to date)
- could you give a minimal example of a constraint (predicate) and a constrained template?

**NOTE:** if you wait long enough I'll try to get the gcc branch running and can at least say anything about the experimental implementation, which however does not imply the correctness of the syntax.

Comment: *will Concepts Lite be part of C++14? (Reference in the standard preferred* What? There's no C++14 Standard yet. Anyway, no, they won't be in C++14. I'll try to find some reference/discussion..

Comment: [The proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf) explains it pretty well. Not that it makes this question illegitimate, not everyone wants to read 30 pages.

Comment: [Stroustrup says on his homepage](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#what-concepts) that they'll end up as a TR to C++14. Not sure how up-to-date that information is, though.

Comment: Also see [this overview at the isocpp.org website](http://isocpp.org/std/status)

Comment: You can easily construct static interface checks using traits and forward instantiation of particular function pointer signatures,

Comment: @Dave: It's not about I'm to lazy to read the document. It's about which one is right (Sutter or Stroustrup). I am unsure if the experimental implementation is subject to change and I couldn't find a reference to that. And actually your document seems more recent than the one I found.

Comment: It won't be in THE C++14 Standard, but an addendum (Technical Report). Depending on how you define "Standard", it's either part of it or not. TRs are not normative according to http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards_development/deliverables-all.htm?type=tr Hmmm isocpp.org says it'll be a TS, see http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards_development/deliverables-all.htm?type=ts this would be normative..

Comment: I *think* it'll be a TS. The drafts have the title "Concepts Lite Specification" and the content fits better to the description of a technical specification than to a technical report. Anyway, it'll not be part of the International Standard as far as I understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concepts Lite is the "constraints" part of a full concepts design for C++. It is described in great detail in [N3701 "Concepts Lite"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3701.pdf). Chapter 2 is a short tutorial that quickly runs through the core principles and their application, which is great for folks that don't want to read through all 56 pages.

Concepts Lite will not be part of C++14, it will be released as a separate Technical Specification later this year.  The latest rough draft for the TS wording is [N3929 "Concepts Lite Specification"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3929.pdf).

There are a few different constraint syntax variants. The code example that Herb used in the talk:

```
auto mean(const Sequence& seq) {
  auto n = 0.0;
  for (auto x : seq)
    n += x;
  return n / seq.size();
}
```

is referred to as the "terse syntax" since it's a shorter equivalent of the verbose syntax:

```
template <typename __T>
  requires Sequence<__T>()
auto mean(const __T& seq) {
  auto n = 0.0;
  for (auto x : seq)
    n += x;
  return n / seq.size();
}
```

They both indicate that the function template `mean` can be instantiated with any type that models the `Sequence` concept. For the sake of simplicity, lets assume that the requirements for `Sequence` are only what our implementation of `mean` needs: (a) members `begin` & `end` that return iterators, and (b) member function `size` that returns some integral type. We could define the concept as:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool Sequence() {
  return requires(T t) {
    {t.size()} -> Integral;
    {t.begin()} -> InputIterator;
    {t.end()} -> InputIterator;
    requires Same<decltype(t.begin()), decltype(t.end())>();
  }
}
```

assuming straight-forward definitions of `Integral`, `InputIterator`, and `Same`. This concept definition ensures that, for some invented value `t` of the type `T` being tested:

- `t.size()` is a valid expression, and it returns a type that models the `Integral` concept.
- `t.begin()` is valid, and returns a type that models `InputIterator`.
- Same for `t.end()`.
- The `InputIterator` returned by `t.begin()` has the same type as that returned by `t.end()`.